# Maven 2 Checkstyle configLocation

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, checkstyle

I have a project which has as maven dependency a jar file which includes a xml file where I stored my rules for checkstyle. I thought it would be ok to just use this configuration:

```
<configLocation>mycheckstyle.xml</configLocation>
```

My understanding is that the file should be searched on the classpath and my jar file is a Maven dependency so it should be found, however I get a resource not found exception.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding a dependencies section to your plugin configuration.

E.g.,

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.whizbang</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

See [Maven Checkstyle Plugin - Multimodule Configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) for more information.

Comment: This was very helpful for our team. Once we realized this was possible, we created simple POM with `jar` packaging just to handle our checkstyle configuration. Now it is much easier to manage, version (if needed), and share across projects.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Checkstyle plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#configLocation),

> configLocation :
>
> Specifies the location of the XML configuration to use.
>
> Potential values are a filesystem path, a URL, **or a classpath resource**.

I never did that on my project...

Are you sure that the JAR containing the XML file is in the classpath when the checkstyle plugin is starting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a parent which specifies the checkstyle plugin and has in its resource folder the appropriate mycheckstyle.xml. I use the maven assembly plugin to make a jar of my parents resource folder and define that jar as a dependency in my child. So when the child inherits the checkstyle plugin + it's configuration from the parent it should be able to find the mycheckstyle.xml. I have followed the instructions on the checkstyle plugin page but it didn't work.

Comment: You mean you did what is explained here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html ?
Can you edit your initial post and put some pom.xml information in it...

Comment: No not exactly like this. It's not multi module. It is simple inheritence a parent to a child. The parent has the  checkstyle plugin within its reporting tag and the child gets it inherited. I add the resources from the parent as jar to the child to have the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local maven repository for your self-created and compiled checks, please be aware to not forget defining

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my local repository</id>
        <url>file:${basedir}/.m2artifacts</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- ... -->
</repositories>
```

but also

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>my local repository</id>
        <url>file:${basedir}/.m2artifacts</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <!-- ... -->
</pluginRepositories>
```

otherwise the plugin dependency will just look in central maven repo but will not find your local JAR file with your check-classes